# ios - How to add checkbox list to UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nstextattachment

I am building a Rich Text Editor, similar to the Notes app on the iPhone and I wanted to know how can I add a checkbox list inside the UITextView?
I assume this can be done using NSTextAttachment but how do I add the tap functionality to check \ uncheck the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i solved this using [HPTextViewTapGestureRecognizer](https://github.com/hpique/HPTextViewTapGestureRecognizer) It appears to do a good job handling tap actions for text attachments

Comment: Using NSTextAttachment and HPTextViewTapGestureRecognizer does help but it does not get the same effect as the Notes app in iOS.
It simply adds a small checkbox image that i can tap, however, the checkbox list in the notes app is a bit more complex - with the ability to mark several lines and add checkboxes to them and then click again to remove the checkboxes.
Any idea how they do that? 
More specifically, how do i "detect" that the selected text is a "checkbox list"