# How can I add checkbox in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox, uitextview, uigesturerecognizer

I am making a TextView similar as **iOS Notes app** and **EverNote**.
and I want to add clickable checkbox list in **Editable**`UITextView`. I tried `UIGestureRecognizer`, but it **didn't** helped a lot.
So is there are some way to add **CheckBox** to `UITextView`?

please help!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36297812/ios-how-to-add-checkbox-list-to-uitextview

Comment: @Sofeda I already tried that one...

Comment: Ever find a solution for this?